# PHP and SQL Hashing Help: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, hash

First off, I am fairly new to coding in general so the idea of hashing is slightly confusing. Essentially, I am trying to hash a password in order to store it in a database so I don't have the password in plain text (I am told this is the best way to do it although I don't think it would be that large of a problem if the passwords weren't hashed as this is only being used in a small group of people that I could inform not to use passwords they care about but I was still advised to do this).

I have looked up a few guides and could use some help with understanding this. I will include the way I am hashing the passwords and how I am pulling them out of the database in order to help understand this problem. Apologies ahead of time if this is a stupid question. Just a heads up, I don't really understand this which is why I am asking the question.

NOTE: Included variables such as $login_username and $login_password are being properly pulled, I just didn't want to include them as it would clutter up this mess of a post even more.

Register user (have tried password_default and password_bcrypt but I don't see a difference):

```
require_once 'database.php';
    $hash_employee_password = password_hash($employee_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = "INSERT INTO employee
                 (employee_id, employee_first_name, employee_last_name,
                 employee_username, employee_email, employee_password)
              VALUES
                 (:employee_id, :employee_first_name, :employee_last_name, 
                 :employee_username, :employee_email, :employee_password);";

    //VALUES (".$employee_id.", '" . $employee_first_name."', '" . $employee_last_name . "', '".$employee_username."', '".$employee_email."', '" . "$employee_password');";

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':employee_id', $employee_id);
    $statement->bindValue(':employee_first_name', $employee_first_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':employee_last_name', $employee_last_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':employee_username', $employee_username);
    $statement->bindValue(':employee_password', $hash_employee_password);
    $statement->bindValue(':employee_email', $employee_email);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();

    //echo $query;
    $message = 'You have been successfully registered. Contact your manager in order to request account confirmation.';
    include ('success.php');
```

Record Login:

```
require_once 'database.php';
include 'register_user.php';

$pwordQuery = "SELECT employee_password from employee where employee_username = :login_username";
$pwstatement = $db->prepare($pwordQuery);
$pwstatement->bindValue(':login_username', $login_username);
$pwstatement->execute();
$result = $pwstatement->fetch();
$pwstatement->closeCursor();


echo $result[0];

if(password_verify($login_password, $result[0]))
{
    echo ' TRUE';
}
else
{
    echo ' FALSE ';
}
```

The problem is: I am entering the proper username and password, but am getting the result of "FALSE" echoed out. Let me know if you have any ideas. Disregard the fact that I have a ton of work to do such as making my queries into functions and calling them that way... That's saved for a later date.

Comment: `"I don't think it would be that large of a problem if the passwords weren't hashed as this is only being used in a small group of people that I could inform not to use passwords they care about"` - I read this as: "I don't think I should have to do things right if I can just tell everyone else to do expect that I'm doing things wrong."

Comment: Is `$login_password` the actual password or the hashed one ?

Comment: password column's length is what? if it's anything less than 60, mysql failed on you silently. 9 times out of 10, that's what the problem is. If so, then you'll need to start all over again by clearing your db and create a new hash.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: @Fred Well it looks like having the column length being 45 was a bad idea and that was my only problem. Thanks for the help, not entirely sure how this site works so I don't know how to give you rep or anything. Also in regards to not hashing the passwords and not fully making security features (@David and @JayBlanchard): this won't be released until I figure out the security features as this is just a beta and I am trying to build a proof of concept before really refining it. I am learning as I go so chances are, I'll make this and then start over and rebuild it from scratch properly.

Comment: @cierex I posted my answer below that you can mark as solved. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"password column's length is what? if it's anything less than 60, mysql failed on you silently. 9 times out of 10, that's what the problem is. If so, then you'll need to start all over again by clearing your db and create a new hash. – Fred -ii- 13 mins ago"*

which I was right about all along:

> *@Fred Well it looks like having the column length being 45 was a bad idea and that was my only problem. Thanks for the help, not entirely sure how this site works so I don't know how to give you rep or anything."*

As per the manual on the `password_hash()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

Comment: Thanks for the help, must have missed the part about character length... Sorry if this seemed like a bad question, as I said, I am new at this :/

Comment: @cierex You're most welcome. Glad to see that you're using a prepared statement also.

Comment: did I accidentally downvote you? If so I apologize as you really helped me out I don't think I downvoted though did I?

Comment: @cierex I don't know. Do you see an orange down arrow or orange up arrow?