# password verify not working to compare hashed password with user entered password

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I am trying to compare a hashed password with a password the user entered but it does not verify and says password incorrect . I used this code to hash the password:`$hashed_password = password_hash($me, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

the code below is the login check page

```
host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbll_name="employees_table"; // Table name 
$tb2_name="system_users";
$tb3_name="managers_table";
// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($link,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$myusername=$_POST["myusername"];  
$mypassword=$_POST["mypassword"]; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection )
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $mypassword);


$statues = "active";

// from system table
if ($sql="SELECT * FROM $tb2_name WHERE User_id='".$myusername."' and statues='".$statues."'");
{

$wql="SELECT * FROM $tb2_name WHERE User_id='".$myusername."' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $wql);
$details = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$Name = $details["Company"];
$Surname = $details["First_name"];
$encrypted_password = $details["Password"];
```

the above code gets the hashed function from database and the below code compares them . but it shows the password is incorrect even they i am typing the correct password

```
if (password_verify($mypassword, $encrypted_password))
{
```

Comment: How about your database can you show us the structure off your table?

Comment: Thank you Adam Hull . The problem was with the data structure of Password. made it varchar 30 instead of varchar 255

Comment: it did . i think the hashed password is greater than 30 characters so it just cut after 30.

Comment: *"The problem was with the data structure of Password. made it varchar 30 instead of varchar 255"* - which is what I meant by [*"Personally, I think it's failing elsewhere"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090555/password-verify-not-working-to-compare-hashed-password-with-user-entered-passwor#comment69386096_41090555) earlier. Edit: @Dagon and they call me crazy.

Comment: @Jerome please consider deleting this question

Comment: ...yeah, [it's been asked recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41003403/1415724) and [answered...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41003701/1415724)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP and SQL Hashing Help: What am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003403/php-and-sql-hashing-help-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: *"That should not off made any difference but your welcome lol"* - @AdamHull - Ummm... yes it would have and their column being too short for the password failed on them *silently*. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php *"Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I had read it wrong I thought he had shortened the varchar to 30 not expanded it from 30

Comment: @AdamHull I see this happen quite often where they fail to go over the entire manuals. They were written to be read completely and not just in part.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something. `stripslashes` **SHOULD NOT BE USED**, especially on passwords.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 3):

> *"i think the hashed password is greater than 30 characters so it just cut after 30. – Jerome"*

Your query failed on you "silently" because the password column is (was) too short and you need to clear out your present password(s)/hash(es) and start over again.

As per the manual on the `password_hash()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

Comment: Why do people always cheap out on column sizes? `VARCHAR(255)` and `VARCHAR(60)` have the same cost internally, but the shorter one will often silently truncate data and lead to tons of headaches. It's not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your if statement to

```
if (password_verify($mypassword, $encrypted_password))
{
```

You had the variables the wrong way and $encrypt was not declared